# Ng-repeat over multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

`localStorage` is an object where the multi-dimensional array I want to iterate on (`localStorage.add`) is stored along with other arrays.

```
<tr ng-repeat = "(key, value) in localStorage track by $index" ng-if = "localStorage.add.length > $index || localStorage.subject.length > $index || localStorage.emailContent > $index" >
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkAllEmail" ng-model="selectedEmail"/>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                    </a>
                </td>

                <td   >
                    {{localStorage.add[$index]}}
                <td>

                <td >
                    {{localStorage.subject[$index]}}
                <td>

                <td >
                    {{localStorage.emailContent[$index]}}
                <td>
        </tr>
```

This is the `localStorage.add` array - `[["Elizabeth","Caroline"],["Patricia"],["Madhu"]]`.

`{{localStorage.add[$index]}}` displays

```
["Elizabeth","Caroline"]        
["Patricia"]            
["Madhu"]
```

I want only the values within the array to be displayed. So, for example, `{{localStorage.add[1][0]}}` displays `"Patricia"` and not `["Patricia"]`. Does anyone have ideas on how to implement this? I tried `{{localStorage.add[$index][$index]}}`, it displays only `Elizabeth` (`{{localStorage.add[0][0]}}`) and not `["Elizabeth"]`. So, I am looking for something similar to `{{localStorage.add[$index][$index]}}` that works for all the elements in the array.

Just to avoid confusion, my app is working as desired. I just don't want the user to see that I am storing these values in an array. This is what the final output should look like:

```
Elizabeth,Caroline      
Patricia
Madhu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the array to string, so in your controller, make a function that your view can call and get a returned string, such as:

```
<tr ng-repeat = "(key, value) in localStorage track by $index" ng-if = "localStorage.add.length > $index || localStorage.subject.length > $index || localStorage.emailContent > $index" >
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checkAllEmail" ng-model="selectedEmail"/>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                </a>
            </td>

            <td>
                {{getNames(localStorage.add[$index])}}
            <td>

            <td >
                {{localStorage.subject[$index]}}
            <td>

            <td >
                {{localStorage.emailContent[$index]}}
            <td>
</tr>
```

This will be in your controller, and you can alter delimiter as needed

```
$scope.getNames = function(names){
  return names.join(',')
}
```

You could probably do this directly in the view like this:

```
localStorage.add[$index].join(',')
```

but I don't recommend it, if it works (not sure)